# How should I document Dojo getters and setters using JSDoc?

Tags: dojo, jsdoc

When declaring a module that extends `dojo/Stateful`, the pattern for getters and setters is to defined `_xxxGetter` and `_xxxSetter` which will be manifested as `.get('xxx')` and `.set('xxx')`.

So, my question is, how best to document this with JSDoc? `@function` doesn't appear to support providing alternate method names and, in anyway, this is a variation on parameter values, not method names?

So, does JSDoc have any inherent support for this model, or do I just need to write explicit documentation for this stuff?

Comment: no IDE intellisence understands dojo.declare or dojo.extend..

Comment: @mschr: I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment. IntelliSense is not JSDoc.

Answer (score 3):

So if its for generating docs alone? Try this: https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc

It is now possible to stack multiple documentation blocks pr variable / function. Dont hang my head on this - but i would believe syntax is like such:

```
{
 ...
 /**
  * Get varname property
  * @returns {mixed}
  *//**
  * Set varname property
  * @param {mixed} val
  * @returns {this}
  */
  varname: null
 ...
}
```